# como usar o foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, estou aqui para solicitar a ajuda dos amigos.
Tenho esse código abaixo para listar todos os produtos e serem cadastrados, mas não estou conseguido listá-los na mesma pagina usando o foreach.
Teria como os amigos me darem uma dica de onde estou errando?
Abraços a todos, e desde já meus agradecimentos pela atenção.

```
   <?php include 'conexao.php';

   $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
   $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
   $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
   $preco = $_POST['preco'];

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos");
   $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   ?>

   <div class="center_content">
   <div class="center_title_bar">Produtos</div>

   <?php
   if (isset($produtos)) {
      foreach ($produtos as $res){
   ?>

   <div class="prod_box">
   <div class="top_prod_box"></div>

   <div class="center_prod_box"> 

   <div class="product_title"><a href="detalhe.php?codigo=<?php echo $res["codigo"];?>"><?php echo $res["titulo"]; ?></a></div>

   <div class="product_img"><a href="detalhe.php?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>"><img width="100" height="auto" src="upload/<?php echo $res['imagem'];?>" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></div>

   <div class="prod_price"><span class="price">R$ <?php echo $res["preco"]; ?></span></div> 

   </div>

   <div class="bottom_prod_box"></div>             
   </div> 

   <?php
     }}
   ?>

   </div><!-- end of center content -->
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? a única coisa que eu vejo que pode estar dando errado é o banco de dados não estar com a estrutura ou os dados que você espera.

Comment: Da onde vem essa variavel `$produtos`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que as variáveis não estão recebendo os valores corretos, verifique se `mysql_query()` não retornou erro, depois disso faça `mysql_fetch_array($query)` em um while e imprima os produtos, caso deseje guarda os itens em array faça `$produtos[] = $res`; O códig deve ficar desa maneira

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos") or die(mysql_error());
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){?>
   <div class="product_title"><a href="detalhe.php?codigo=<?php echo $res["codigo"];?>"><?php echo $res["titulo"]; ?></a></div>
   <div class="product_img"><a href="detalhe.php?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo']; ?>"><img width="100" height="auto" src="upload/<?php echo $res['imagem'];?>" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></div>
   <div class="prod_price"><span class="price">R$ <?php echo $res["preco"]; ?></span></div> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: `while() : ` e depois `endwhile;` pra ficar mais organizado!

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda rray, funcionou na boa.
Abraços, e até a próxima.