# Como funciona realmente o foreach no PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Alguem poderia explicar como realmente funciona o foreach e como usar? Eu ja pesquisei e não consigo entender, ja vi aqui mesmo no stackoveflow, tem [ESSE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83383/como-usar-o-foreach) tópico, mas não está explicado, só gostaria de entender, porque estou estudando, e estou na parte de vetores e matrizes e começou a aparecer o foreach, e não estou entendendo.

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Como o foreach funciona, não consigo entender essa função, o que ela faz.

Comment: Ela percorre os elementos de um array basicamente. Tem algum exemplo de código que mostre algo que vc náo entendeu? o for/foreach não são funções são estrutura de repetições. O `foreach` é uma versão direto ao ponto do `for` nele você não precisa controlar o indexador, incremente ou decremento e a condição de parada.

Comment: o "as" significa o que?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho o `as` separa a chave do valor: `forearch( $colecao as $chave => $valor ) { ...`

Comment: O que vem depois do `as` vc pode interpretar como o elemento iterado (atual)

Comment: Acredito que isso responda melhor: [Qual a diferença entre o while, for, do while e foreach?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157512/91)

Comment: Esse artigo deve te ajudar @LucasCarvalho: https://medium.com/weyes/usando-estruturas-de-repetição-no-php-7b51cf34247a